# How to pre-load on boot all activities in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I'd like to solve a "too much waiting" problem. Hi to everybody :)

The case is that i've an application with a main menu that has 2 buttons. I'll paste the manifest here so you can see what I'm talking about.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="razvitrance.administradorcontraseas.PantallaPrincipal"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_pantalla_principal"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="razvitrance.administradorcontraseas.PantallaPrincipalAdministrar"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="razvitrance.administradorcontraseas.PantallaAyuda"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_pantalla_ayuda"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="razvitrance.administradorcontraseas.PantallaAdministraroGenerar"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_pantalla_administraro_generar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="razvitrance.administradorcontraseas.PantallaPrincipalGenerar"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_pantalla_principal_generar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="razvitrance.administradorcontraseas.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash_screen"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My main menu called .PantallaPrincipalAdministraroGenerar has 2 buttons and each of them call the new .PantallaPrincipalAdministrar and .PantallaPrincipalGenerar activities.

Well, my problem is that when I push the first of them, it takes no time to show the activite because it seems that that activity is already loaded, but when I push the second one the .PantallaPrincipalAdministrar takes too long until it appears on front and I do see on android studio's console how it is loading and creating all the files & allocating all the memory.

Is there any way I can preload all my activities in the boot of the app or while the splashscreen??

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily you cannot really. And you are most likely addressing problem in wrong place - if your activity takes too long to start check what you are doing in `onCreate()`, offload some tasks to background thrads, rework your ui, use Fragments, use lazy initialization etc, etc.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your attention. I'm programming in android for 6 days or so, so I'm not that expert.